# Spring testcontainers Driver org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, testcontainers

Having following configuration for my integration tests I ran into following exception:

`Driver org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32864/test?loggerLevel=OFF`

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = WebApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
@TestPropertySource(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "application-test.properties")
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Container
    protected static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgresqlContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgresqlContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgresqlContainer::getPassword);
    }

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertThat(mockMvc).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(postgresqlContainer.isRunning()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

The `postgresqlContainer.getJdbcUrl()` returns `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:32864/test?loggerLevel=OFF`
But it should return `jdbc:tc:postgresql://...`, its missing the **tc** part.

Any solution to this ?

Hardcoding it like: `String.format("jdbc:tc:postgresql://localhost:%s/%s", postgresqlContainer.getFirstMappedPort(), postgresqlContainer.getDatabaseName())` seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please see the big orange warning here:
https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/

You should use either the JDBC URL with `tc:` prefix and `ContainerDatabaseDriver` or container instance with `getJdbcUrl()` and the original driver (or let the system detect the driver for you), not both.

Comment: And given that the postgreSqlContainer is generating the jdbc, how do you pepuse to add the 'tc:' prefix?

Comment: @EranFriedland I do it like this now: `registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> "jdbc:tc:postgresql:13.11://ignored:1111/" + postgreSQLContainer.getDatabaseName());` whereas registry is a DynamicPropertyRegistry (method argument of a method annotated with `@DynamicPropertySource`)

Answer (score 4):

In my case just added the postgresql dependency (it includes the driver) and it worked:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My test class:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@Testable
public class PostgreSqlContainerLiveTest {

    @Rule
    public PostgreSQLContainer postgresContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:9.4");

    static {
        // Postgres JDBC driver uses JUL; disable it to avoid annoying, irrelevant, stderr logs during connection testing
        LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSelectQueryExecuted_thenResultsReturned() throws Exception {
        ResultSet resultSet = performQuery(postgresContainer, "SELECT 1");
        resultSet.next();
        int result = resultSet.getInt(1);
        assertEquals(1, result);
    }

    private ResultSet performQuery(PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer, String query) throws SQLException {
        String jdbcUrl = postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl();
        String username = postgreSQLContainer.getUsername();
        String password = postgreSQLContainer.getPassword();

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
        return conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    }
}
```

I hope that this could help to you or someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have both `dependency testcontainers postgresql`  & `dependency postgresql` at your config file.